# Copy a .sav file from Appdata and place in a folder on desktop

Tags: c#

To be able to copy a .sav file from the appdata and place it inside a folder on the desktop. This is for a game I play and to make it easier for myself and my friends to have the save file on the desktop rather than having to go looking for it.

How do i go about specifying the location of the file in the appdata section, once set, click save and it places the file in a folder on the desktop.

I've not tried anything yet as I am not sure how to proceed.

@Sach suggested the following code but I don't know how to implement the code.

```cs
Find AppData and Desktop folders:

var appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

Then there are a multitude of ways to move a file, this is one of them:

if (Directory.Exists(appData) && Directory.Exists(desktop))
{
    var file = Path.Combine(appData, "1.txt");
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        File.Move(file, Path.Combine(desktop, "1.txt"));
    }
}
```

To have the save file on the desktop backed up.

Comment: Right. And what happened when you tried that code?

Comment: According to the purpose, you are not like to solve a programming question. If you only want to copy files, ask in [superuser](https://superuser.com/) is better.

Comment: @shingo if he wants to do the copying with code then it's a coding question...

Comment: What exactly is the question here? It seems you have the code you need, on first glance it seems similar to what I would write.

Comment: @BeLostTwice. A little friendliness goes a long way on SO. If you respond the way you did above, people tend to not help you

Comment: @BeLostTwice please don't be rude or sarcastic. both Laser and I have asked you a simple question about your code. You're asking how to do it..but then you already have some code, which suggests you understand a way to do it. So we just want to know what the problem is, exactly? Does the code not do what you expected? Please clarify the issue. Then we can help you more precisely. But if you'd rather mock those who want to help you then you might find that they don't help twice.

Comment: I apologise, as stated, I've not tried anything yet as I am not sure how to proceed.
@Sach suggested the following code but I don't know how to implement the code. I can open a new form and see the code, but I don't know how to place the code or what I need to place on the form. I am also looking at the WPF Project below and also trying to add that too which is confusing, don't give me the answer, do let me try and work it out for myself, we have all been there, I am sure you were in my position a long time ago. I am just frustrated.

Comment: Ok. So how do you want to trigger this saving? When should it happen? When you start the program? When you click a button? When some other event happens? Knowing that will help you determine where to place the code. And what kind of application have you written? Console app? Winforms? Something else?

Comment: If not set, have the user set there username so the program knows where to obtain the file once the username has been set. Once set, having a button say save, a text box showing the location of the file but greyed out. Windows Form. I've got a basic layout of how I want it, its just a matter of implementing the code.

Comment: Ok so do you know how to handle a button being clicked? Your code should go in the function which runs when the button is clicked

Comment: Yes, place the button, double click it and place the code.

Answer (score 1):

hope this will solve your questions,
if you have any other question fill free to ask me.

**this is WPF Project**
XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <TextBox Name="txtSourceFile" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="11,23,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsEnabled="false" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="442"/>
        <Button Margin="454,23,39,269" Content="..." Click="Button_Click" />
        <Label Content="SourceFile:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,-3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtCopyPath" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Margin="11,71,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" IsEnabled="false" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="442"/>
        <Button Margin="453,71,40,221" Content="..." Click="Button_Click1" />
        <Label Content="Copy Path:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Margin="124,170,124,83" Content="Copy!" Click="Button_Click2" />
    </Grid>
```

XAML.CS:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace copy_file
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog dlg = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
                dlg.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
                dlg.Filter = ".sav Files (*.sav)|*.sav|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
                if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    txtSourceFile.Text = dlg.FileName;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }

        private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
                dlg.SelectedPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);             
                DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
                if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    txtCopyPath.Text = dlg.SelectedPath;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }           
        }

        private void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
        {
            if(txtCopyPath.Text.Length>1 && txtSourceFile.Text.Length > 1)
            {                    
                string fName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(txtSourceFile.Text);
                System.IO.File.Copy(txtSourceFile.Text, txtCopyPath.Text +"\\"+ fName, true);
                success = true;
            }
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Info", success.ToString());
            success = false;
        }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used the WPF before, i've created the project and added the grid to the form and applied the code. When I try to add the above the code is loaded but comes up with an invalid window., I don't know how to do this.

Comment: give me picture or error details I cannot guess what is the problem, also I have tested it before I answered

Comment: Ok lets start off with the first part of the code, I open the form and add the grid then I go to the code and add the code between the 2 <grid>. Once ive done that it then shows up on the gui the parts shown, Looks like 3 buttons and 2 text boxes source file and copy path. So I am pretty sure I got that right, then I go to the MainWindow.xaml.cs file and I suppose that is where the 2nd part of the code goes correct?

Comment: I am not sure how to go about adding the 2nd part of the code into the form.

Comment: just put the functions without the main method and the namespace thing....

Comment: This isn't working, since I dont know what i am doing and just trying based on the code: The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'

Comment: So many WPF which one am I supposed to use? I picked the first one WPF App (.NET Framework) I don't think its this one because the moment I mention forms it errors out.

Comment: Cant use this in WPF - Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'

Comment: in project tree you have references -> right click - add reference -> in the assembly search for System.Windows.Forms -> check and add to your project. this will solve yours issue